# How to avoid swiping the navbar with back swipe navigation

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I have default webview swiping in the capacitor app made via https://georghoeller.dev/capacitor-ng-back-swipe/amp/

The problem I'm facing is: my navigation (on the bottom) swipes along with the page content (as it is a part of the page).

I want the navigation to stay in place and only content could be swiped back / forward.

I can think about possible solution to this - having 2 different WKWebViews (separate views for `<Navigation/>` and for `<Content/>`) that communicate with each other would solve this, but is it possible with capacitor? Is this something to look in Subclassing CAPBridgeViewController | Capacitor Documentation?

[image]

Comment: you need to have your nav overlay and then have a content window which you can do the paging in

Comment: could you point me the direction to achieve it with capacitor? https://capacitorjs.com/docs/ios/viewcontroller is this something to look in?

Comment: yes use the viewcontroller